# function works in javascript file but not in html file

Tags: javascript, html, function

Can you please check why funtion listfiles is not working.
If I put it in a seperate js file and run, logs show the needed output.
But inside html, nothing is displayed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>
The global function (listfiles) returns the filenmes with certain pattern:
</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function listfiles() {

var Extras = "19ibxiuX-xcyNXGs4GBNR_W8zLXSz3mhS";
var filetype = "text/csv";
var filenameformat = /^Report-\w{3}-[A|D]-\d{8}.csv$/;

var fileIterator = DriveApp.getFolderById(Extras).getFiles();

var file;
var filenames = [];
var count = 0;
//Logger.log(count);
filenames[0]="";
//Logger.log(filenames[count]);

while (fileIterator.hasNext()) {
    var file = fileIterator.next();
    //Logger.log(file.getName().search(filenameformat));
    if (file.getName().search(filenameformat) == 0 && file.getMimeType() == filetype) {
    count = count + 1; 
    filenames[count] = file.getName();
    Logger.log(count);
    Logger.log(filenames[count]);
    Logger.log(file.getMimeType());
    }
   };
 return filenames;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = listfiles(); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you including  the js file in the html after transferring the code?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the function your calling and the actual function names are different.
Change listnames() to listfiles() or viseversa

Comment: Sorry my bad. I already fixed that and still it does not work

Comment: I also commented all the Logger lines and still the same